# Django - Pass a dictionary to template through the get_queryset function of a class based view

Tags: python, html, django

Is there a way to return a dictionary through the get_queryset function of a class based view in Django? I want to pass the array tickets and the string email to my template, but I am only able to pass tickets right now.

Content of `views.py`:

```
class UserTicketListView(ListView):
    model = Ticket
    template_name = 'ticket_system/user_tickets.html'
    context_object_name = 'tickets'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        email = User.objects.get(username=user).email
        return Ticket.objects.filter(author=user).order_by('-date_posted')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class UserTicketListView(ListView):
   model = Ticket
   template_name = 'ticket_system/user_tickets.html'
   context_object_name = 'tickets'
   ordering = ['-date_posted']
   paginate_by = 5

   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
     context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
     queryset = self.get_queryset()
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
    email = User.objects.get(username=user).email
    queryset = queryset.filter(author=user).order_by('-date_posted')
    context['user'] = user
    context['email'] = email
    return context
```

Comment: Thanks Dimitris, adding this function along with `def_queryset(self)` works perfectly!